# (MATLAB) Extracting numerical values from strings included eponential form numbers

Tags: string, matlab, abaqus

I have an array of strings containing mixed text and numbers, example strings provided below:

```
            TOTAL STRAIN ENERGY (STRESS POWER)          5.126778E-05

 STEP TIME COMPLETED        20.0    ,  TOTAL TIME COMPLETED         20.0
```

I would like to extract the strain energy values as numbers, as well as the total time completed values. I've tried using scanning to find the location of the text preceeding the numbers then reading off partial strings using str = str(start:end) but this returns 0 for any length for some reason?

Comment: You can use a regular expression in your case this one `(TOTAL STRAIN ENERGY \(STRESS POWER\)|TOTAL TIME COMPLETED)(?:\s+)?(\d+.\d+(?:E-)?(?:\d+)?)`, where the first group is the variable name and the second group is the associated value. `?:` indicate that the parenthesis is a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

```
StrOut = "TOTAL STRAIN ENERGY (STRESS POWER) 5.126778E-05 STEP TIME COMPLETED        20.0    ,  TOTAL TIME COMPLETED         20.0  ";
StrOutSplit = split(StrOut, {'TOTAL STRAIN ENERGY (STRESS POWER)', 'STEP TIME COMPLETED', ',  TOTAL TIME COMPLETED '});
StrOutSplit(1) = [];
outNum = cellfun(@str2num, StrOutSplit);
```

Comment: next time it is better to provide a minimal example